# Jitsi server hardware requirements on test environment

Tags: server, hardware, video-conferencing, jitsi

We are implementing secure videoconferencing/chat using Jitsi. We could not find any hardware requirements for a Jitsi server. Could you please share your thoughts regarding the hardware requirements for a Jitsi server in test as well as production environment?

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 5):

I am using https://github.com/matrix-org/docker-jitsi on a free tier Ec2 instance.

With 1 active conference (8 participant). it didn't seem to spike resource consumption. You can observe that CPU usage is 0.0 & used RAM is about 450MB.

[image]

Comment: What browser was used by participants? Where is the video transcoding done?

Answer (score 1):

The hardware requirements will depend on the amount of users you have. From what I've seen, Jisti does not require huge resources to run smoothly.

According to this [Jitsi Videobridge Performance Evaluation](https://jitsi.org/jitsi-videobridge-performance-evaluation/)

> On a plain Xeon server that you can rent for about a hundred dollars,
>   for about 20% CPU you will be able to run 1000+ video streams using an
>   average of 550 Mbps!

Answer (score 0):

For that thing, we need to get an idea about how many simultaneous conferences go there and how many participants at each conference.
Another special parameter is how many users enable their video stream and audio stream. And their network bandwidth.Based on that we can decide server requirements.